# computing eigenvalues without normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be $k \times k$ matrix and $x$ be a $k \times 1$ vector that satisfy

$Ax-\left(\frac{1}{1-x'x}\right)x=0$

Then, of course, the eigenvalue is given by $\lambda=\frac{1}{1-x'x}$. But the eigenvector $x$ has the norm different from 1:

$x'x=1-\frac{1}{\lambda}$

I'm trying to obtain the eigenvalues of $A$ by R or Matlab. However, these softwares automatically normalize the eigenvectors so that the norm becomes one.

My question is how to compute the eigenvalues of $A$ when only R or Matlab that imposes unit norm restriction is available.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: If $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $cx$ for any scalar $c\ne0$, so your first equation can only hold for $\le k$ specific vectors $x$. Are you trying to recover these specific vectors?

Comment: Yes, I want to compute $x$.

Comment: In Eigenvalue problems, $\lambda$ does not depend on $\vec x$. What you have proposed is a non-linear problem expressed in terms of matrix A. Just because there is a matrix does not make it a Linear problem. Also in most cases $\vec x = \vec 0$ may be the only solution.